# Df without NA gives error: Error in cov.wt(y, wt = wt) : 'x' must contain finite values only

Tags: r, na

I'm using the package relaimpo to calculate the proportional contribution of each covariate to the R2 of a linear full model. Recently, I updated this package what confronts me know with the following error message:

```
SUBJECT Days    Volume
P003    1   51640.33
P003    211 55109.29
P004    1   10259.38
P004    140 10269.75
P004    252 10526.75
P004    364 8560.62
P007    1   177.38
P007    368 266.65

> library(relaimpo)
> Full_model <- lm(Volume~SUBJECT+Days, data=Test)
> calc.relimp(Full_model, diff = T, rela = T)
Error in cov.wt(y, wt = wt) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

I checked already the posts on this website. They all seem to suggest that this is due to missing values. But when I remove the missing values from the dataframe (as in this test dataset) I still get this error message. Also when I additionally define x=NULL in the script or try to add instructions how to handle NA values, I still get the same error.

Anybody an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: non finite can also refer to `Inf/-Inf` values try subsetting with `is.finite`

Comment: Indead, when I ran is.finite(Test$SUBJECT) the command returned FALSE. So I formatted the SUBJECT column as factor and now it works perfect again! Thank! I had no clue!